# Unambiguous expression for binary strings containing some substring

Tags: combinatorics, binary

Is there some systematic way for finding an unambiguous expression for a binary string which contains a certain substring? For finding expressions *not* containing a substring, it is sometimes easy to just stare at the problem until you get this concatenation of first, middle, and tail; how to do so for binary string containing some substring (say 11101)?

Comment: Can you give an example? For instance, what if the substring is just 1?